# Makefile - How to get the path of src/header files

Tags: makefile

Can someone explain me how i do a Makefile getting the source files from a folder named src and the header files from a folder named headers? And then the executable files and the object files being stored on the current folder? Just a basic example to help me out ;). thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
OBJ := foo.o bar.o

thing: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) -c -Iheaders $< -o $@
```